# How to push the latest data entered based on conditions on Google AppScript?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently, the code below checks the if the data meets two criteria and then it's pushed into an array, but the need now is to get the latest data that meet those criteria.
The date's index within the dataset is [19] (20th column).

How would I go about tweaking it?

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         if (values[i][0] == productCode && values[i][2] == productVersao) {
        data.push(values[i]);
    } 
  }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
function themostrecent(values) {
  values.sort(function(a,b){
    var A=new Date(a[19]).valueOf();
    var B=new Date(b[19]).valueOf();
    return B-A;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == productCode && values[i][2] == productVersao) {
      data.push(values[i]);
      break;
    } 
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Two questions here:
01 - It ends up pushing the first row whose criteria are met, while there is usually more than that where I'm getting the data from.
02 - I've declared a couple of variables above values.sort to get the values'  range, so that I don't see an error. Do I actually need to declare these variables in every function, or a function can inherit variables/ranges from other functions?

Comment: All I’m really saying is if you sort your array so that the most recent rows are the beginning of the array then the first row that meets your other criteria is the most recent so if put that before the loop that’s all you need. I would have done that but you didn’t provide it so I couldn’t do that